# Showing that the Geometric distribution $E(X)=\frac 1p$

Tags: probability, expectation

So I have $X \sim  \text{Geom}(p)$ and the probability mass function is:

$$p(1-p)^{x-1}$$

From the definition that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ns^{n-1} = \frac {1}{(1-s)^2}$$

How would I show that the $E(X)=\frac 1p$

Comment: What you call a definition is not a definition. Perhaps you could call it a proposition or simply a fact or, in this case, a lemma. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray}
 E(X)&=&\sum_{x=1}^\infty x p(1-p)^{x-1}\\
&=&p\sum_{x=1}^\infty x(1-p)^{x-1}\\
&=&p\sum_{x=1}^\infty -\frac{d}{dp}(1-p)^{x}\\
&=&-p\left[\frac{d}{dp} \sum_{x=1}^\infty (1-p)^x\right]\\
&=&-p\cdot \frac{d}{dp}\frac{1-p}{1-(1-p)} \\
&=&-p\cdot \frac{d}{dp}\frac{1-p}{p} \\ 
&=&-p\cdot \frac{-1}{p^2} \\
&=& \frac{1}{p}\\
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

What is $s$ in your case? Consider:

$$
E(X)=\sum_{x=1}^\infty x p(1-p)^{x-1}=p\sum_{x=1}^\infty x(1-p)^{x-1}=\cdots=?
$$

Can you see how to take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way would be to plug in $q=1-p$ and solve it that way using formula for geometric sequences:

\begin{align*}
E(X) &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty kpq^{k-1}\\
&= \frac{p}{q} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty kq^{k}\\
&= \frac{p}{q} \frac{q}{(1-q)^2}\\
&= \frac{p}{q} \frac{q}{p^2}\\
&= \frac{p}{q} \frac{q}{p^2}\\
&= \frac{1}{p}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$p(1-p)^{x-1}$

\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}(X) & = \sum_{x=1}^\infty x\Pr(X=x) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty x p(1-p)^{x-1} = p \sum_{x=1}^\infty x(1-p)^x \\[10pt]
& = \underbrace{p \sum_{n=1}^\infty xs^{x-1} = p\cdot \frac 1 {(1-s)^2}}_{\text{This is the identity that you cited.}} \quad \text{where }s=1-p, \\[15pt]
& = p\cdot \frac 1 {p^2} = \frac 1 p.
\end{align}